# VSCode: "Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information."

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've literally spent over 3 hours trying to figure out why my VSCode is unable to unistall new extensions. It gets stuck in this forever download tooltip at the bottom right of the screen and for hours nothing happens but the error message in the title is occasionally seen.

[image]

This happened as soon as I upgraded my vscode to the latest version. I'm currently using version 1.57.1 of VSCode. I've literally searched every where on the internet but nothing seems to help. I'd appreciate any advice.